# Why is my cable not working?

Tags: thunderbolt, mac-mini, hdmi

I recently got a new, long **Thunderbolt to HDMI** cable to play films on my projector from my **Mac Mini**.
However, I cannot get the new cable to work on my **Mac Mini**.

I checked and the Thunderbolt port of the Mini works fine with the older cable. I also checked, and the cable works fine with my other computer, a **Macbook Air**.

What could possibly be the issue preventing me from using the new cable with the **Mac Mini**?

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>Mac Mini mid-2011, macOS High Sierra</sub>

Comment: Probably manufacturing tolerances - both on port & cable.

Comment: @SolarMike can you explain?

Comment: How long is the new cable compared to the old cable? - The new cable might be out of spec.

Comment: Did you checked the thunderbolt versions of Mac mini and new cable ?

Comment: @jksoegaard the new one is longer (that’s why I bought it, the other ones are too short to reach the projector)

Comment: @PtitXav I will! Good idea

Comment: We know it’s longer - but exactly how long?

Comment: @jksoegaard the new one is 3 meters